# Why does WAS admin console queue configuration not accept asterisk (*) as Queue Manager entry?

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, ibm-was

I am configuring WAS to connect to MQ via CCDT, and should be using a Queue Manager Name with wild cards, i.e *QMan.

It is accepted in the Queue Connection Factory Screen and in the Activation Spec Screen, but it is not accepted in the Queue Configuration Screen. As shown on the below image, I am forced to leave the Queue Manager field blank. And my application is not received MQ messages. I am suspecting this might be the reason.

Any ideas why I cannot configure the Queue Manager in Queue screen? And what is the common problem if message listener is not receiving, even if the MQPUT is working.

I had double checked my CCDT configuration in Activation Spec, and have check the jndi names, everything is configured correctly.

Also note that it is working if I connected directly to the MQ via host/port etc. But I have to use CCDT to utilize our MQ cluster.

[image: WebSphere Admin Console Queue Configuration Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Queue Manager (or Queue Sharing Group) name on the JMS Queue panel defines *where* the queue is located and not *how* you connect to it. It is the Queue Manager name in the JMS connection factory or activation specification that defines which queue manager your application connections to.

So it is correct that you can't enter a * in this box.

If the connection is not working when using a CCDT then it is likely to be another problem that this Queue Manager name box. Note: you can't use an XA connection with CCDTs due to the fact that a CCDT won't guarantee you will connect back to the same queue manager in the event of XA recovery.

Comment: Thanks for this information, however am still stuck on why MessageListener is not picking up messages. As for the XA recovery, I can only see XA Recovery on the security portion, which I am leaving as blank.

Comment: I would check the SystemOut.log on the WAS server for errors and the open input count on the queue in question to see if the message listener is connecting to the right place.

Comment: Figured it out, the problem is before CCDT configuration the TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED. Now it is changed to TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED  and disabled QCF's "Support distributed two phase commit protocol".